# Sharing feature classes between different geodatabases?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, autocad

We're starting to work on different projects. All of them have their own data and classes but some of them are common (ex. parcels, traffic, road definition, etc.).

How can I share feature classes across projects?

I found only these approaches:

I could take from the source geodatabase but I cannot create relationships or make a copy in each geodatabase but I have the risk that some of them will not be updated (in any case I have to do manually).

My environment is based on ArcGIS and AutoCAD and it could be that we do an upgrade buying ArcGIS server.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that the ideal solution would be to upgrade to ArcGIS Server so you can take advantage of replication capabilities built into ArcSDE technology.  You can get more information about ArcGIS's Distributed Data capabilities at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Understanding_distributed_data/003n000000ts000000/

In general though, replication is probably what you are looking for in that it would let you have multiple databases, all sharing specific datasets, that you can set up to keep synchronized, so you only have to edit the shared data once and all the copies of the dataset stay updated with those changes.  The other point to note about this though is, if you are needing multiple copies of the data because you are trying to work on it in different offices that don't have strong connectivity between each other, great, that's what replication like you're asking about would help with.  However, if you are needing multiple copies so multiple people can be viewing it from the same office at the same time... all you'd need to do is use a File Geodatabase on a shared network location (ex: a server's share folder or NAS drive) since File Geodatabases support multiple concurrent read-only connections to the data (though only one connection is supported at a time if it's being edited).  This may work if it's just base-map type data that you don't edit frequently.  If you're needing multiple copies of the data because multiple people need to edit the data at the same time, you definitely need to invest in ArcGIS Server so you can take advantage of ArcSDE and versioning, which supports multiple concurrent editors working with the same dataset.

If your only goal behind having multiple copies of the same datasets is so you have a copy in each project folder though, that may be a waste of storage space and a needless complication of your workflow.  ArcGIS Desktop supports connecting to multiple data-sources within the same map.  So, you could have your base-map data such as roads and parcels all in one database in one spot that you read that data from for all of your maps for all of your projects.  Then, you could still have separate project databases for project specific datasets.  ArcGIS Desktop does not require all data for a specific project to be lumped into one specific project file or database.